# Double.NaN isCloseTo double value unexpectedly returns true

Tags: java, nan, assertj

AssertJ returns `true` when checking if a double is close to NaN. Is this a bug?

```
assertThat(Double.NaN).isCloseTo(0.00811, Percentage.withPercentage(0.1));
```

The version used is *3.6.2*.

Comment: If asking about a possible bug, you should include the exact version you're using.

Comment: I am also wondering about that super low Percentage value. Wouldnt surprise me it that is causing issues, too. Beyond that: probably not the first bug on this specific checker: https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/611

Comment: edited to include version and increased percentage value

Comment: The bug is in assertIsCloseToPercentage They should check if the diff result is NaN. The following is always false for Double.NaN
        if (absDiff(actual, other).doubleValue() > acceptableDiff)
      throw failures.failure(info, shouldBeEqualWithinPercentage(actual, other, percentage, absDiff(actual, other)));

Comment: YES, it is a bug, see [Issue#984](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/984) (from today [:-) )

Answer (score 1):

As [Carlos Heuberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85421/carlos-heuberger) pointed out in his comment, this was [a bug](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/984). It was featured in both the *2.X* and *3.X* branches.

It has since been fixed in both branches, in versions *2.8.0* and *3.8.0*.

I just tested `assertThat(Double.NaN).isCloseTo(0.00811, Percentage.withPercentage(0.1));` and it now fails, as expected.